# Simulador de supermercado C

Tags: c

Tengo un problema con el siguiente código. El ejercicio trata de simular una fila que tiene número aleatorios de gente que pasa por tres cajas, cuando una caja está vacía se quita un elemento de la fila original y pasa a la caja C1, C2 o C3 y una vez allí después de un delay decrece el valor de el número que está en cualquiera de esas tres cajas; cuando ese valor es de cero, se saca de la caja y queda vacía por lo que otro elemento de la fila original entra en la otra.
El problema es que al ejecutar, en las cajas me muestra basura y según yo no debería pasar eso.

```
void caja(FILA *F)
{
    FILA C1, C2, C3; crearFila(&C1); crearFila(&C2); crearFila(&C3);
    TipoDato a, b, c;
    do
    {
        x=dequeue(F);
        Sleep(2000);
        if (filaVacia(C1))
        {
            enqueue(&C1, x);

            if (a==0)
            {
                dequeue(&C1);
            }
        }
        else if (filaVacia(C2))
        {
            enqueue(&C2, x);
            if (b==0)
            {
                dequeue(&C2);
            }
        }
        else if (filaVacia(C3))
        {
            enqueue(&C3, x);
            if (c==0)
            {
                dequeue(&C3);
            }
        }
        system("cls");
        printf("\nFila: \n");
        imprime(*F);
        printf("\nCaja 1: \n");
        imprime(C1);
        printf("\nCaja 2: \n");
        imprime(C2);
        printf("\nCaja 3: \n");
        imprime(C3);
        if (!filaVacia(C1))
        {
            a=dequeue(&C1); a--; enqueue(&C1, a);
        }
        if (!filaVacia(C2))
        {
            b=dequeue(&C2); b--; enqueue(&C2, b);
        }
        if (!filaVacia(C3))
        {
            c=dequeue(&C3); c--; enqueue(&C3, c);
        }
    }while(!filaVacia(*F));
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Mucho me temo que sin un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), va a ser difícil ayudarte. ¿ Que función falla ? ¿ `crearFila( )`, `dequeue( )`, `enqueue( )`, `imprime( )` ? ¿ O incluso `filaVacia( )` ? ¿ Que es `FILA` ? ¿ Has intentado *localizar* el problema de algún modo ?

Answer (score 0):

```
TipoDato a, b, c;
do
{
    x=dequeue(F);
    Sleep(2000);
    if (filaVacia(C1))
    {
        enqueue(&C1, x);

        if (a==0) // (1)
        {
            dequeue(&C1);
        }
```

En la primera línea declaras tres variables: `a`, `b`, `c`. En `(1)` comparas `a`... que no está inicializada. Y lo mismo pasa con las otras dos variables.

Sin más información todo apunta a que tu problema es que estas tres variables no están inicializadas.